# Dune: Imperium faction cards require no specific influence to buy?

Tags: dune-imperium

I've watches several videos, played two games, and read the rules a couple times. There doesn't seem to be a requirement of any specific amount of influence with a faction to buy a card from the Imperium Deck?

For example, I may spent 2 persuasion to buy this card even if I have never increase my influence with the spacing guild? 
[image: card to buy]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, you **do not** need any kind of specific Faction influence to buy cards from the Imperium Deck. The only thing you need is persuasion.

For reference, Page 11 of [The Official Rulebook](https://www.direwolfdigital.com/dune-imperium/resources/rules/) on acquiring cards says:

> The Persuasion you gain during a round is used during your Reveal turn to acquire new cards for your deck. You may acquire any of the five cards in the Imperium Row, or *Arrakis Liaison* or *The Spice Must Flow* from the Reserve.

Some cards and decks benefit from having the same faction. For example, The Fremen Bond (Explained on page 16 in the **Icon Guide and Additional Terms** page) gives you a bonus if you've played multiple Fremen Faction cards during your turn. Expansions may (or may not) expand on this idea further.